# Can't get UILabel to display from boolean condition

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't for the life of me figure out why this won't work. I'm trying to display a label after determining a boolean condition. No matter what I do, the label won't display. So in a pathetic desperate attempt, I put the code to display the label inside a button event to force it to display. Now it works perfectly (from the button click). But it still won't work from the boolean condition!

This is in viewDidLoad (note that the 'true' is just to isolate where the fault is):

```
if (true) [self showSubscribeLabel];
```

This is from the button click:

```
- (IBAction)askUserToSubscribe:(id)sender {
    [self showSubscribeLabel];
}

-(void) showSubscribeLabel {

    NSLog(@"here");
    self.subscribeLabel.hidden = NO;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.viewUnauthorized];

}
```

I see the output `here` when the controller loads and then again after clicking the button. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Is your `showSubscribeLabel` method being called (from the BOOL condition)? Show the actual code for the condition check.

Comment: Try moving your test to `viewWillAppear` rather than `viewDidLoad`

Comment: That is my actual code. I'll build out the rest of it later after I get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move your test and method invocation to `viewWillAppear` - often things aren't fully initialised in `viewDidLoad`.  Having the code in `viewWillAppear` will also ensure that the condition is evaluated every time the view controller appears (such as when another view pops off a navigation stack) rather than when it is loaded for the first time.